# Shell Exec StdOut to Existing console

Tags: console, autohotkey, wsh

So I know how to use `wscript` to launch a console, send and read from it,

but what about doing this with an existing console window?

(*I have the functions divided up in such a way as I can use them separately for other reasons)*

How can I send and receive lines from a console I've previously created?

```
Startconsole:
    LaunchConsole(showconsole)  ;display console based on user settings
    DllCall("AttachConsole", "UInt", conWinPID)
return

LaunchConsole(hideconsole=0){
    global
    if(hideconsole){
        hideconsole := "hide"
    }
    Run %ComSpec% /K cd /D c:\test, c:\test, %hideconsole%, conWinPID
    winwait, ahk_pid %conWinPID%
    winsettitle, ahk_pid %conWinPID%,,My Console Title
}

ConsoleCommand(whatcommand){
    global myEdit
    oExec := ComObjCreate("WScript.Shell").Exec(whatcommand)
    While, !oExec.StdOut.AtEndOfStream
        result := oExec.StdOut.ReadAll()
        guicontrol,, myEdit, %result%
    Return, result
}

CloseConsole:
    DllCall("FreeConsole")
    winclose, ahk_pid %conWinPID%   
return
```

So I want to do this:

```
gosub, StartConsole
ConsoleCommand("ping google.com -n 1")
ConsoleCommand("ping somewhereelse.com -n 1")
gosub, CloseConsole
```

The lines from the console should display in both my edit control AND in the console that I created in `LaunchConsole` rather than the one I am created in the wscripting.  I need to make the wscript work with my console.

*[update]*

I think it actually *might be* using that console - it's just that the commands I send via wscript don't display in the console, AND whatever I type in the console is not fed back into the script.

Comment: LibCon.ahk has the ability to attach itself to any standard console and control it, ie read/write

Comment: Hi, Joe!   I have the link here: https://github.com/joedf/LibCon.ahk

Comment: right, forgot to post the link... :P

Comment: JoeDF - it seems like libcon only lets ahk talk through a console window.  I can't see any way to get it to interact with a regular console; that is, you can't send a `ping` command to it (or I can't figure it out from your docs).  Care to post an example?

Comment: Here's your libcon ahk thread: http://ahkscript.org/boards/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=17&p=39851#p39851